# kafka endpoint to Azure EventHub using Confluent Dotnet

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I have a need to stream messages from a *third party* Kafka stream endpoint, then send those messages to an Azure Event Hub for processing.

Currently at a high level the design is as follows:

```
  1.  Create a Consumer using the Confluent dotnet client library
  2.  Create a batch(not sure how many messages yet).  To reduce requests. 
  3.  Use Azure.Messaging.EventHub to send those message batches to EventHub. 
  4.  This all would run in an Azure app service as a web job.
```

Is there any other way that doesn't require this piecemeal approach?  I've seen other products like mirror maker, and a few posts on Kafka for event hubs but that seemed like when you own the Kafka client and you can use Event Hub as a psuedo Kafka broker.

Does this seem like a reasonable approach?

Comment: What is wrong going with MirrorMaker? It is the perfect tool for your scenario.

Comment: I don’t have access to the Kafka side to co figure it.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca and it also seems that mirror maker is for replication purposes.  Seems like the wrong use case but I'm new to Kafka so I could be wrong.